# angular reactive form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need reactive form which result will be like this

I tried some codes but something wrong.

```
[{"account":{ "accountNum": "numbers which user will type in input" }}]
```

Comment: pls help me i need it :( write it on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr2pf9

Answer (score 3):

Givi, you has an array with one element, inside the array an object with a propertie "account" that is another object with a propertie "accountNum" that is a string

```
myForm=new FormArray([       //an formArray with one element
    new FormGroup({          //that is a formGroup with a propertie "account"
      account:new FormGroup({//that is a formGroup with a propertie "accountNum"
                             //    that is a FormControl
        accountNum:new FormControl("numbers which user will type in input") 
      })
    })
  ])
```

Too see in the .html

```
<pre>{{myForm?.value|json}}</pre>
```

You see that if you has an array you need a FormArray, if you need an object, you need a FormGroup and if you need a value, you need a FormControl. Please, try understand, not simply copy and paste the answer.

**Updated** show a .html to change the form

Well, you can use a unique formControl

```
<input [formControl]="myForm.at(0).get('account').get('accountNum')">
```

But we are going to learn how manage a formArray. Normally if a formArray is a propertie of a formGroup we use some like

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
   <div formArrayName="myArray">
      <div *ngFor="let controls in myForm.get('myArray').controls;
               let i=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
               <!--here the controls of our array-->
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

If we can manage an array we need know that a formArray is a formGroup, so we can make some like

```
   <!--see that we used [formGroup]-->
   <div [formGroup]="myArray"> 
      <div *ngFor="let controls in myArray.controls;
               let i=index">
            <!--see how replace the [formGroupName]="i" by [formGroup]="controls"
                      the variable of the *ngFor -->
            <div [formGroup]="controls">
            <!--here the controls of our array-->
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I wrote like this and it works <3 https://pastebin.com/raw/2Lu1Twwi something wrong ?

Comment: If you has severals fileds (or if your formArray can store more than a unique element), use the code I indicate in the answer. see your example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubckvt?file=src/app/app.component.html. It's important you understand that both ways (yours and mine) say the same. You can use formName="..." or [formControl]="myform.get('...')

Comment: the formGroup (or the formArray) exist independienty we has an input or not. An the input can get/set the value of the form control using severals ways