# How to get the value of list with same formcontrolname?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-forms

I have 4 inputs which are generated using loop . And I am using angular forms for UI , but the problem is I am getting only last input value and the requirement is I need all the input values provided I cannot generate the formControlName dynamic . Is there any way to bypass only getting the last value and get all values ??

The HTML code for the same is(this loop will execute based on dataArr,here assume it is executing 4 times)  :

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
   <div *ngFor = "let data of dataArr;">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Key" value={{data.key}} formControlName="key"/>

   </div>
</form>

<button type="button" style="background-color: #4980FF;" (click)="save();">Save</button>
```

The code in .ts file :

```
  // it is initializing and registering the form value
  dataForm = new FormGroup({
    key: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])

  });

  save(){
   // Here I am trying to print the form value 
  }
```

I am looking to get all the values when I click save button and not only the last value .

Comment: I wont recommend the way you have created the form. In such scenarios use `FormArray` Instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FormArray` instead

In your component, create your `FormGroup` and `FormArray`.

```js
this.dataForm = new FormGroup({
    key: new FormArray(this.dataArr.map(data => new FormControl(data.key, [Validators.required])))
    // Add other form groups or form controls here
});

save() {
    console.log(this.dataForm.value);
}
```

Bind these controls in your `form` like below. You don't need to `value` attribute because `FormControl` will bind the value for you instead.

```html
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
    <div *ngFor="let data of dataArr; let i = index" formArrayName="key">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Key" [formControlName]="i" />
    </div>
</form>

<button type="button" style="background-color: #4980FF;" (click)="save();">Save</button>
```

Comment: if you only need a form Array, use only a formArray -it's not necesary create a formGroup with a formArray inside, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622872/angular-reactive-form-array/56623003#56623003

Comment: @Eliseo - I was of the opinion that the questioner had other data in his `FormGroup` and posted only the relevant data for his issue. @NeerajNauni - If there is no other data in the `FormGroup`, then yes, creating just a `FormArray` should be sufficient.

Comment: @NeerajNauni - Let me know if the solution is working for you

Comment: @nash11 not exactly, I did some tweaking in that .

Answer (score 0):

When working with an array of items in forms where you might need to add controls or remove controls or even editing the values of existing items always use angular FormArray.

Below is a working example of FormArray.. Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7z9if)
More on [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray)

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormArray
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  dataForm: FormGroup;
  items: FormArray;
  dataArr: any;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataArr = [{
          key: 'First'
        },
        {
          key: 'Second'
        },
        {
          key: 'Third'
        },
        {
          key: 'Fourth'
        }
      ];
      this.createItems();
    }, 2000)
  }
  createItems() {
    this.items = this.dataForm.get('items') as FormArray;
    this.dataArr.forEach((elem: any) => {
      const ctrl = this.formBuilder.group({
        key: [elem.key]
      });
      this.items.push(ctrl);
    })
  }


  save() {
    console.log(this.dataForm.get('items').value)
    return this.dataForm.get('items').value;
  }

}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
  <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of dataForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Key" formControlName="key" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" style="background-color: #4980FF;" (click)="save();">Save</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The data in dataArr will come from the API and the problem is that since the API call will be async in nature , the form is rendering first and then the API is getting called , so my dataArr is showing null , while rendering the form.

Comment: So thats not a problem at all just use a *ngIf on the form.. Updated the Code to execute when the api has returned the result.. I have added a setTimeout of 2 sec after which the dataArr object is set and the form is loaded.. This solves your API data issue..

Comment: But dataArr size is not fixed and also it doesn't contain any key like 'key'

Comment: Thats OK dataArr can be of any size doesnt matters all the items will be displayed. Also that property key is what i have set to demonstrate FormArray you can use whatever you want or whatever is the property in dataArr..